# Application crash with error Exception has been thrown by the target

Tags: c#, winforms

i have Winform application who run all the files within listbox,
i am using Pcapdotnet DLLs to send packets into my network adapter, the process is that i am taking Wireshark capture file and with this file send all the packets.
each file will run with BackgroundWorker and after it's finished the next time in my listbox srart to run etc.
i added a Checkbox and when this Checkbox in checked state all the files run in the same time simultaneous.
when it's running my application crash with error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in:

```
static void Main()
{
    Adapters addr = new Adapters();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new mainWindow());
}
```

the error received in the last line (Application.Run(new mainWindow());)

this is my code who handle in simultaneous running:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string filePath  = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
            playCount = 0;

            BackgroundWorker bgWsim = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWsim.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bgWsim.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgW_ProgressChanged);
            bgWsim.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {
                while ((playCount < numberOfLoops) && (bContinuePlay)) //play the capture
                {
                    for (int k = 0; (k < listBoxFiles.Items.Count) && (bContinuePlay); k++)
                    {
                        class = new myClass(filePath , playSpeed);

                        class.evePacketProgress += new class.dlgPacketProgress(
                            (progressCount) =>
                            {
                                bgWsim.ReportProgress(progressCount, class);
                            });

                        if (selectedAdapter != null)
                        {
                            bContinuePlay = class.playCapture(selectedAdapter._packetDevice);
                        }

                        playCount++;
                        Thread.Sleep((int)delay);
                    }
                }
            });

            bgWsim.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {
                groupBoxSelect.Enabled = true;
                groupBoxOptions.Enabled = true;
                groupBoxInfo.Enabled = true;
                btnPlay.Enabled = true;
            }
            );

            bgWsim.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

how can i debug this error and find the problem ?

error screenshot:

http://i42.tinypic.com/2ainbqp.jpg

Comment: You can debug this error by hitting F5 and using breakpoints.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Seems like a mulithreading issue with winforms controls

Comment: Can you give us full exception text and stack trace?

Comment: the crash happen after i start to run all the files and happen sometimes after few seconds and sometimes after few minutes

Comment: how can i do it ? (exception text and stack trace)

Comment: screenshot link added (last line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) has `Maximum` and `Minumum` properties that are used to define the range of values that it will accept (defaulting from 0 to 100). If you try to set the `Value` property to a number outside of the range, it, will throw an ArgumentException. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value.aspx).

Comment: my ProgressBar  is my problem ?

Comment: The value you are passing through to it. I suspect you are doing this in your `bgW_ProgressChanged` method (which you've defined as your `ProgressChangedEventHandler`). One approach would be to express your `progressCount` variable as a percentage (so it will be a number in the range 0-100), and pass that to `bgWsim.ReportProgress()` instead.

Comment: See the start of your stack trace - `at System.Windows.Forms.progressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)`, and your exception message says `Value of '101' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.`.

Comment: thanks a lot it's OK now, i disabled the ProgressBar, in any case has no meaning in simultaneous mode

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the RunWorkerCompleted event since its called by the async thread.You need to edit controls from Windows Forms on their own thread you can do this by invoking the control.

Example : (with lambda)

```
        private static void runOnThread(Control x, Action logic)
    {
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            x.Invoke(logic);
        }
        else
        {
            logic();
        }
    }
```

You will call this as follwed:

```
runOnThread(groupBoxSelect,() => groupBoxSelect.Enabled = true );
```